# Nextion Editior of Graph

Tags: nextion

I've been working with Nextion display for Two week. I'm trying to build a Graph, how can I use x-axis, y-axis with the nextion Editor. Anybody pls tell me if how to create axis in the graph.

Thanks in Advance